# How to grep for alphabets followed by a space and a punctuation mark?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a line called

```
10909101 - testingName - Log8767, File787 - 8:50PM
```

Now I just want to use grep to get `testingName` as my output.

The first number may vary in terms of number of digits(another line may have `12` itself as the first number), so I can't use any number based grep. So how do I solve this?

Comment: Does it have to be `grep`? delimited data is something that `awk` excels at

Comment: Will the format of all lines be identical?

Comment: @John Yes except that the numbers and names maybe of varying length.

Comment: @steeldriver Well grep is the only thing that I know of as of now, so was wondering if I could perform this using grep.

Answer (score 3):

Given that all data will be identically formatted, `grep` is the wrong tool for this. It's usable, certainly, but using it is a kludge - this isn't what `grep` was designed for, and a much better tool is `awk`.

Since your delimiter will always be a "space, dash, space" sequence, i.e. `-`, you can do this:

```
$ awk -F' - ' '{print $2}' <filename>
```

where `<filename>` is the name of the file with the data you're searching, and you will get all lines from the entire file trimmed to just the second entry. If you don't like using a three character delimiter, you can do this:

```
$ awk -F- '{print $2}' | tr -d ' '
```

which simply grabs everything from the first `-` to the second, including the spaces, and removes the spaces via `tr`. Of course, if you have spaces in your filenames, that would cause problems, and you'll want to stick to the first example.

Answer (score 0):

This uses *two* instances of `grep`, but it *is* pure `grep`:

```
echo '10909101 - testingName - Log8767, File787 - 8:50PM  ' | \
grep -o '\- [[:alpha:]]* \-' | grep -o '[[:alpha:]]*'
```

Output:

```
testingName
```